# Ask for storage permission from static class in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, user-permissions

I want to check if storage permission is granted or not from static class.I don't  have activity object as the static class extends Application.
I used the following code from activity

```
checkSelfPermission(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
```

But from static class it throws error as it is a non static method

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Temp {
    public static void requestPermission(Activity act) {
            int status = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (status != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Logger.e("permission not granted");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 4322);
            }
        }
    }
```

call

```
Temp.requestPermission(activity/context);
```